# Can you recommend an URL shortener, where the short link dies after a given time from the first click?

Tags: web-apps, url, timer, url-shortening

I would like to use such an URL shortener, to somehow protect the link content.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one? Check Picture1: Expiration date and time settings on Short.io (formerly short.cm)

https://short.io/features/link-expiration